# 再次 and 再: are they different?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Here is the context: 我于是去了这家餐厅，点了一盘蘑菇菜心，果然好吃。我对服务员说: 我再次要一盘。

The sentence "我再次要一盘" is wrong. But "我再要一盘" is correct. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Just an FYI, to people downvoting, the answers below, please post a comment as to why you think it's wrong or inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by  Camila Ting Chen is close. We don't use 再次 in an present *active* sentence. We use 再次 with some perfectness or passiveness. Such passiveness is not necessarily related to the conjunctive 被 however. A simple rule is when we can say 再 alone, say it alone.

我再次来到这家餐厅。

我时隔数年再次遇到一位朋友。

这盘菜再次被我吃掉了。 while this sentence is not logical at a first glace, it sound good in this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

我再次要一盘 is "I want the dish again."

我再要一盘 is "I want another one."

It's one of those things that you can say it and people would know what you mean. But it just sounds off.

Comment: it seems iciba gives a good idea of the exact meaning of either：
 再次：once more ； a second time ； once again ；again 
 在：another time ； again ； still ； further ； anew

Comment: @S.Rhee If the case is as what you wrote here, both sentences should be correct. But "我再次要一盘" is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

我再次要一盘 should exist in 陈述句

我再要一盘 should exit in 祈使句

As you are asking the waiter, it's 祈使句.

Answer (score -1):

When the 再+ verb, normally, we dont use the 次.
Let's look the sentence again， “我再要一盘”， here “要” means want， is a verb，so, just use 再+verb. If you say: “我再次要一盘”， weird, but not wrong, we can understand.